# Behaviour of Locator

Tags: graphics, manipulate, locator

I seek advice regarding the constrained behaviour of the Locator: appears confined to square {0,0}->{1,1}. When I change starting position it snaps to this constrained region.

The code I am referring to follows:

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{cn, d}, cn = {c1, c2, c3}; 
  d = Norm[# - pt] & /@ {c1, c2, c3}; 
  Graphics[{{Black, Point[cn]}, 
    MapThread[{#1, Circle[#2, #3]} &, {{Red, Green, Blue}, cn, d}]}]
  ],
 {pt, {1, 1}, ControlType -> Locator, LocatorRegion -> Full},
 Initialization -> (c1 = {0, 0}; c2 = {3, 0}; c3 = {0, 3};)
 ]
```

The constraint remains whether I define PlotRange, use `EuclideanDistance` or otherwise define the distance function.

The following graphic shows (obviously) this is well defined outside the region of constraint of the `Locator`. Intersection point at {4,4}with  fixed points at{0,0}, {1,0}, {0,1}.

[image]

Image generated by:

```
Graphics[{{Black, Point[cc = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}}]}, {Red, 
   Point[{{4, 4}}]}, Map[Circle[#1, Norm[# - {4, 4}]] &, cc]}]
```

---

I can get around the constraint using `Slider2D` but I am still uncertain about the Locator issue.

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{cn, d}, cn = {c1, c2, c3}; 
  d = Norm[# - pt] & /@ {c1, c2, c3}; 
  Graphics[{{Black, Point[cn]}, {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[pt]}, 
    MapThread[{#1, Circle[#2, #3]} &, {{Red, Green, Blue}, cn, d}]}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}]
  ],
 {pt, {-4, -4}, {4, 4}, ControlType -> Slider2D},
 Initialization -> (c1 = {0, 0}; c2 = {1, 0}; c3 = {0, 1};)
 ]
```

Thank you @Nasser I look forward to trying your code.

Comment: Thank you @Mr.Wizard, for edit. Makes question more readable. Am sorry it was syntax error/understanding error on specifying Locator. Questioned answered and learned something. Whole point, I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've have not used `Locator` for a while. But please try this (I am not sure if this is what you asking about either, but this makes the locator free to move anywhere in the `PlotRange` given in the `Graphics`), if this is not what you meant, will delete this

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{cn = {c1, c2, c3}, d},
  d = Norm[# - pt] & /@ cn;
  Graphics[{
    {Black, Point[cn]},
    MapThread[{#1, Circle[#2, #3]} &, {{Red, Green, Blue}, cn, d}
     ]
    }, PlotRange -> {{-6, 6}, {-6, 6}},
   Axes -> True]
  ],
 {{pt, {1, 1}}, Locator},
 Initialization :> 
  (c1 = {0, 0};
   c2 = {3, 0};
   c3 = {0, 3};
   )
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Nasser. If I change the syntax of my the specification of the Locator from {pt,{1,1},Locator...} to {{pt,{1,1},Locator} as in your code it resolves my issue without axes or plot range. A coding misunderstanding by me now resolved.